# How to Sanitize or validate SQL query in spring boot to prevent SQL injection?

Tags: sql, spring-boot, sql-injection, sanitization, owasp

I know that query parameter and JPA repository is safe for injections.
But I want to use some dependency or library to do this.
is there any plugging that develop by the OWASP for this ?
Is there an Annotation for this ?

Please can someone put a link for that ?

Comment: What dependency or library do you want to use?

Comment: what ever thing that work fine and easy to use

Comment: Spring Data JPA works fine. Any reason you want to use something else?